# Getting an image from a header

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a SSRS 2005 rdl file, which contains a header section. The header section has a logo image.
I need to know where in the rdl file is the logo image stored?
The logo is to be used for other reports.

Thanks

FC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the author created the report. You can have 1 of 4 methods to store images for use in a report:

1. Embedded - The report is embedded in the actual report file
2. Project - The image is stored in the Report project and shared across the reports within the project
3. Database - the image is stored in a db
4. Web - The image is linked from a location on the web

If it is embedded, your rdl will include an  element with the actual file contents inside of the element.

If it is a Project image, it will be inside of an  tag.

There will be corresponding tags for DataBase and Web images as well, although I have never dealt with them.

Comment: It is embedded. How do I locate the element with the actual file contents?

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to do this. Once it's embedded, all the binary data is inside the file. You might try to google how to decode this data, but I've never had any experience with it.